# java switch statement not ignoring the cases not listed

Tags: java, string, switch-statement, bitset

I want to ignore all other characters besides A, G, T, C, but when I put N at the end of the string, it prints out 00. the output should be 00 0101 1010 1111, 
but it is 00 0101 1010 1111 00. I used the default case in the switch statement because I thought this would ignore all other characters besides the ones listed. Is there something I am doing wrong?

```
import java.util.BitSet;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args){

      String originalString = "aCCGGAATTN";
      int bitSetSize = 2 * originalString.length();
      BitSet bitSet = new BitSet(bitSetSize); 

      originalString = originalString.toUpperCase();

      for (int i = 0; i < originalString.length(); i++) {

          switch(originalString.charAt(i)){
          case 'A':
              bitSet.clear(i * 2);
              bitSet.clear(i * 2 + 1);
          break;

          case 'C':
               bitSet.clear(i * 2);
              bitSet.set(i * 2 + 1);
          break;

          case 'G':
              bitSet.set(i * 2);
              bitSet.clear(i * 2 + 1);
          break;

          case 'T':
              bitSet.set(i * 2);
              bitSet.set(i * 2 + 1);
          break;

          default:
              break;

          }

      }

      // print all the bits in the bitset
      for (int i = 0; i < bitSetSize; i++) {
          if (bitSet.get(i))
            System.out.print("1");
          else
            System.out.print("0");
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Use a debugger it place print statements around to see what's going on.

Comment: @PaulAbbott this was my issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's the the `switch` that's the problem, it's the fact that you're using indices into your original, unfiltered string, to decide which bits to set.

Use two different variables to keep track of the input and the output indices:

```
  for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < originalString.length(); i++) {

      switch(originalString.charAt(i)){
      case 'A':
          bitSet.clear(j * 2);
          bitSet.clear(j * 2 + 1);
          j++;
      break;

      ...

      }

  }
```